# SF short story, probably pre-1980 featuring a girl with a strawberry birthmark

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I think I read this in the late 70's, but it could have been a bit later.

Set in the future, a detective is investigating a murder or disappearance (I think). Society has gone one step further than the current trend of getting botox to make your lips look like Angelina Jolie; in the story, you can buy a whole 'look' and get surgery to transform yourself accordingly.

The protagonist watches some sort of presentation (not sure he's supposed to be there) which features the latest look. The original model has a birthmark in the shape of a strawberry on her bottom (or possibly her back), and the presenter mentions that this has been left in place and will form part of the package. At this point, the main character realises he knows the girl and determines to search for her... Pretty sure it was a short story

Comment: this reminds me of a story written by maybe MW Shelley or some other famous gothic author of that period and the subject was also a birthmark, one which her scientist husband hopes to remove so his spouse will be even more perfect.

Comment: @releseabe You're remembering [The Birth Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Birth-Mark). However it's not the story being asked about here.